# DLL in nuget references Version=0.0.0.0

Tags: c#, nuget

I have the following situation:

There is a library LibF which I build as a nuget package, it contains dlls for net48 and net core 3.1. I am the person packing it directly from the csproj using:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It has the version="4.2.0-alpha.55" (I use GitVersion). Then I have another library LibD that uses LibF, so it references it as a nuget package in the .csproj like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="LibF " Version="4.2.0-alpha.55" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then I also create a nuget package from LibD. I am the person packing it directly from the csproj using:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When I try to consume the nuget of LibD somewhere else I get a compile issue in Visual Studio 2019:

```
Error   CS0012  The type 'MyType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
You must add a reference to assembly 'LibF , Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
PublicKeyToken=468d6536c503beba'.
```

Obviously I don't have version 0.0.0.0. Now when I look at the nuget package (unzip) I see the following entry in the LibD.nuspec:

```
<dependency id="LibF" version="4.2.0-alpha.55" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
```

This is correct. But when I use JetBrains DotPeek to analyze the dll it tells me in the references of the dll:

```
LibF, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=468d6536c503beba
```

So my question is: Why is there Version=0.0.0.0 as a reference for the dll? Why does it not want 4.2.0.0 because that is the version I have and the version I would expect to be referenced by the dll.

What could lead to such an issue?

Comment: This sounds like a packaging problem in the library. Have you contacted the library author? Is it your own library? If so: how are you packaging it, exactly?

Comment: I edited to answer your questions. I package it myself with Visual Studio directly from the csproj, not with a separate nusepc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was missing was the following in the PropertyGroup of the csproj:

```
<UpdateAssemblyInfo>true</UpdateAssemblyInfo>
```

Afterwards version of assembly is correct.